# SQLite data into Excel?

Tags: excel, sqlite

I wish to pull data from a large SQLite database into Excel. I'll want to do so quite interactively so don't want to export CSVs or anything like that. I have seen the sqliteodbc website on ch-werner.de but does that work with Excel 2007?

What are the best options?

Comment: how many tables do you have? need to export all or just one? how often?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually I have gone through the ch-werner.de file mentioned in the question and it works well, even in Excel 2007. Simply make sure to register your database using the ODBC option in the Windows control panel.

Answer (score 0):

Excel recognizes XML and the format is something like this:-

```
<Workbook xmlns=\"urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet\" xmlns:x=\"urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel\" xmlns:ss=\"urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet\" xmlns:html=\"http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40\">
<DocumentProperties xmlns=\"urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office\">
```

You might want to create a sample of the output you want in Excel, save it as XML data. Open your regular text edit, and voila... you got the XML skeleton.

Now programmatically converting SQLite to Excel, that's another thing. You didn't mention what language you're conversant with.

Comment: Thanks rockjock. I work with Python. Was hoping for a more direct solution but I think this could work.